# Disable JSP servlet in Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using Spring with Jetty. Until now I haven't used JSP's, but I have a 3rd party servlet that uses them.

It appears in the logs that Jetty is trying to load a "jsp" servlet. But I want all requests to go through to springs dispatcher servlet.

What can I do to stop Jetty from intercepting *.jsp?

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:...

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SPRING DISPATCHER SERVLET ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- Allows Spring to handle all web requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SPRING SECURITY HOOK ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- removed for clarity -->

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ BEAN SCOPES FOR WEB ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- removed for clarity -->

</web-app>
```

**Jetty logs for a non-JSP request:**

```
28902 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - REQUEST /myaccount/transactions on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$3@52d85409
28902 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - Got Session ID 1x85qr20xozki139cfcd6a520o from cookie
28902 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@21e3cc77
28902 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager$HashedSession:1x85qr20xozki139cfcd6a520o@1420624050
28902 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - servlet=dispatcher
28903 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - servlet holder=
28903 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - chain=
28903 [qtp1620636050-15 - /myaccount/transactions] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - call filter springSecurityFilterChain
```

**Jetty logs for a JSP request:**

```
398317 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - REQUEST /console/login.jsp on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$3@1eaf0e38
398317 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - Got Session ID 1x85qr20xozki139cfcd6a520o from cookie
398317 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@21e3cc77
398318 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager$HashedSession:1x85qr20xozki139cfcd6a520o@1420624050
398318 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - servlet=jsp
398319 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - servlet holder=
398319 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - chain=
398319 [qtp1620636050-14 - /console/login.jsp] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - call filter springSecurityFilterChain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<servlet-mapping>*.jsp</servlet-mapping>` to map this extension to your dispatcher servlet.